# Finding non-cyclic subgroups in $\mathrm{Z}_{40}\oplus\mathrm{Z}_{30}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, modular-arithmetic, direct-product

A question in a section on external direct products in Gallian’s 9th edition Contemporary Abstract Algebra asks for an order $12$ cyclic subgroup and an order $12$ non-cyclic subgroup from $\mathrm{Z}_{40}\oplus\mathrm{Z}_{30}$. Finding the cyclic subgroup was easy, but I don’t know where to start with finding the non-cyclic one. I tried including elements of the form $(a,0)$ and $(0,b)$ in order to generate other potential elements for such a subgroup, but I didn’t succeed.

As a matter of fact, I always end up getting stuck in these questions asking for non-cyclic subgroups of groups. Sometimes computing a subgroup of the form $\langle x,y \rangle = \{x^sy^t \mid s,t \in \mathrm{Z}\}$ works, but what is a good strategy? Filtering out elements with tools like Lagrange’s Theorem?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint:  What can a non-cyclic abelian group of order $12$ look like?  There's only one such group (up to isomorphism).

Comment: So you’re saying to find a subgroup isomorphic to $\mathrm{Z}_6\oplus \mathrm{Z}_2$?

Comment: I did that and got a subgroup. Thank you.